# how to insert comma in sql expression

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have code line like this:

```
  "select count(1) from tblEquipmentRegister where EquipmentID = " & Me.cmbEquipmentID.Value & " and StartTime is null"
```

which results this string:

```
  "select count(1) from tblEquipmentRegister where EquipmentID = 203203,16 and StartTime is null"
```

when I pass this string to function

```
  Public Function getOneValue(strSQL As String)
  Dim q As QueryDef
  Dim rec As Recordset
  Set q = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qTmp")

  q.SQL = strSQL
  Set rec = q.OpenRecordset

  getOneValue = rec.Fields(0).Value

  Set q = Nothing
  Set rec = Nothing

  End Function
```

I get `syntax error (comma) in query expression`
 I don't get error if `EquipmentID` is number without a comma. 
How should I construct string with a comma in the `EquipmentID`?

Comment: Enclose the EquipmentId with in single quote.   "select count(1) from tblEquipmentRegister where EquipmentID = '" & Me.cmbEquipmentID.Value & "' and StartTime is null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(1) from tblEquipmentRegister where EquipmentID = 203203,16 and StartTime is null
```

should be

```
select count(1) from tblEquipmentRegister where EquipmentID = '203203,16' and StartTime is null
```

In short

```
select * from table where val=number
```

is correct if value is integer.

but if it's a string then you should use

```
select * from table where val='some string'
```

So `203203,16` is `string` and `20320316` is number, that's why it works fine without comma.

So you should edit your code to

```
select count(1) from tblEquipmentRegister where EquipmentID = '" & Me.cmbEquipmentID.Value & "' and StartTime is null
```

Comment: then I get `data type mismatch in criteria expression` on the code line `set rec = q.OpenRecordset`

Comment: that's a must do, you can't enter string in integer data type.

Answer (score 2):

If there is any possibility that EquipmentID could contain a single quote, the above code will fail.

I use a function qString to both wrap the string in quotes and to double-up any embedded quotes:

```
    ' Return string S quoted, with quotes escaped, for building SQL.
    ' O'Connor -> 'O''Connor'
    Public Function QString(ByVal s As String) As String
       QString = "'" & Replace(s, "'", "''") & "'"
    End Function
```

If all you want is the record count, you can get it much more easily with the DCount built-in function. This single statement will replace all of your code:

```
    getOneValue = DCount("*", "tblEquipmentRegister", _
                  "EquipmentID = " & QString(cmbEquipmentID) & _
                  " AND StartTime IS NULL")
```